# Rounded Corner images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I've been trying to do perfectly shaped circular images with non-square images. I tried to make it with

```
[self.photoView.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];
[self.photoView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

It becomes something like this:

[image: Not so perfectly rounded]

I want to make it full perfect circular.

PhotoView's content mode is setted to Aspect Fill, It's height and width fixed to 80x80 with autolayout. I could not figure it out.

I made circular images with cropping and scaling them, but also want to add a border to it, in this way i need to recreate new uiimage to draw borders in it. It's expensive thing. I want to use photoView's layer to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set corner radius is half of `width/height` (for square object only) so it will create round view.

```
[self.photoView.layer setCornerRadius:self.photoView.frame.size.height/2];
```

or set it to `40.0f` because your height and width is 40x40.

Comment: As I said, I am fetching user's facebook profile picture. It's sizes are not always square. My image view's content mode is Aspect Fill. This solution gives perfect diamond. :)) https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw7mt2lru22khwi/Screenshot%202014-12-03%2011.31.12.png?dl=0

Comment: @taskiner can you please tell how you crop and scale image?

Comment: Setting cornerRadius to `40.0f` did the trick. I am not sure why setting it with `frame.size.height` produced awkward result. But thanks, i think setting it to `40.0f` is not produce any errors in future because its frame is always be 80x80 with autolayout am i right?

Comment: @Hemang Content mode is Aspect Fill, It automatically resizes to fit height or width in it. I only need to show it circular I am not trying to fit Image in it perfectly. I don't think it will produce any problems.

Comment: @Hemang frame is fixed so i dnt think so that it will create any issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, corner radius should be half of the `width` or `height` of the provided photo view and it must be square in shape.

So the code go like this:

```
[self.photoView.layer setCornerRadius:CGRectGetHeight(self.photoView.frame)/2];
[self.photoView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using layer and mask:

```
CGFloat imWidth = photoView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat imHeight = photoView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat minSize = imWidth < imHeight ? imWidth : imHeight;
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(imWidth * 0.5f - minSize * 0.5f, imHeight * 0.5f - minSize * 0.5f, minSize, minSize);
maskLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, minSize, minSize), nil);
photoView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

This crop the photoview according to a circle inside the `photoview.frame`.
You can change minSize to:`CGFloat maxSize = imWidth > imHeight ? imWidth : imHeight;`
if you want another effect.

Answer (score 1):

try this
Import the QuartzCore `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` header and play with the layer property of the `UIImageView`.

```
self.photoView.layer.cornerRadius = self.photoView.frame.size.height/2;
self.photoView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: As i said, photo view's images are dynamically loaded, so they are not square always. With this solution photoView's layer becomes like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw7mt2lru22khwi/Screenshot%202014-12-03%2011.31.12.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

swift code:

declare

```
@IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!
```

viewDidLoad or any method:

```
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleView.frame.width/2
circleView.layer.borderWidth = 10
circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```

objective-C code:

declare UIImageView

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myimageview;
```

viewDidLoad or any method,

```
myimageview.layer.cornerRadius = myimageview.frame.size.width/2;
myimageview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
myimageview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
myimageview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```